# Apache POI hyperlinks with sheets

Tags: java, excel, apache

I have a excel file which consists of two sheets

sheet1: consists of error_id and no of errors as column's names(both are integer 
         values).

sheet2: Error_Id and description are column's here.

When user clicks on error_id column value in sheet one we should automatically go to that particular error_id in sheet2 so user can find description there for that particular error id.

I want to automate it using java and apache POI, please suggest me with code sample's.

Please help me.

Comment: why not use [google??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705648/hyperlink-to-a-different-sheet-within-the-same-workbook-using-apache-poi)

Comment: I could not found resources with using sheets.

Comment: `apache poi hyperlink to sheet` as search term and first result

Comment: I found the coe but its not dynamic..https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/HyperlinkExample.java..I need get according to error_id..